# Cygwin 1.7.x fails to translate windows path to POSIX path

Tags: cygwin, msbuildcommunitytasks

Year or so hence, I modified a project of mine to include subversion revision in installer file name.
I installed MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets and modified csproj file so that it contained:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
...
<SvnVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" ToolPath="C:\cygwin\bin">
   <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
</SvnVersion>
...
```

This worked like a charm. However, after upgrade to cygwin 1.7, following error started to occur when running build process:

> C:\cygwin\bin\svnversion.exe --no-newline
> "Z:/cygdrive/z/dev/myproject/src/winservice"
>
> '/cygdrive/z/dev/myproject/src/winservice/Z:/cygdrive/z/dev/myproject/src/winservice'
> doesn't exist
>
> Z:\dev\swiftarhiv\src\myproject\myprojectservice.csproj(200,5): error
> MSB6006 : "svnversion.exe" exited with code 1. Done Building Project
>
> "Z:\dev\swiftarhiv\src\myprojects\myprojectservice.cspro j" (Rebuild
> target(s)) -- FAILED.

I tried modifying LocalPath parameter of SvnInfo task to "." or "/cygdrive/z/dev/myproject/src/winservice", but SvnInfo task has a nasty habit of using windows full path no matter what you put in so "." resolved to the path used before and "/cygdrive/z/dev/myproject/src/winservice" resolved to "Z:/cygdrive/z/dev/myproject/src/winservice" which caused an error again.

Is there a setting I can set in Cygwin 1.7 that will make my problems scarce?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to deliberately use a particular path format, you could use the `cygpath` utility.

```
$ echo $PWD
/cygdrive/c/Windows

$ cygpath -ua .
/cygdrive/c/Windows/

$ cygpath -wa .
C:\Windows
```

Without knowing the particulars of the Subversion build process, would it be possible for you to set the LocalPath by passing that MSBuildProjectDirectory object through it?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to tie my build process to Cygwin. Currently, the only thing connecting build process with Cygwin is location of bin directory (set in ToolPath parameter). So, if I download some other subversion client and change that directory, I don't have to change ought else. However, if I use cygpath, I add one more thing to be aware of and which will most certainly be forgotten.

Comment: Also, calling cygwin won't help. If I set LocalPath="/cygdrive/z/dev/myproject/src/winservice", Svninfo community task, will automatically append drive letter (in my case Z:) in front of it. this of course will result in same error.